# Form Filter with Pagination not working in Django

Tags: django, forms, filter, paginator

I am trying to use Form filters and Pagination together in a view and only one works at one point of time, I am not able to make both work together, Please help if there is a workaround to my problem.

**views.py**

`

```
def viewAmc(request):
    amc = Amc.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(amc, 10)
    page_obj = paginator.page(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    amcFilter = AmcFilter(request.GET, queryset=amc)
    amc = amcFilter.qs#qs means query set
    context = {'amc': page_obj,
               'amcFilter': amcFilter}
    return render(request, 'view_amc.html', context)
```

`
**filters.py**

`

```
class AmcFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Amc
        fields = 'amc_type', 'amc_status'
```

`
**view_amc.html**

`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h5>&nbsp; Annual Maintenance Contract :</h5>
           <div class="card card-body">
               <form method="get">
                {{ amcFilter.form.amc_type.label_tag }}{{ amcFilter.form.amc_type }}
                {{ amcFilter.form.amc_status.label_tag }}{{ amcFilter.form.amc_status }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Filter</button>
            </form>
                           </div>
                <div class="col">
    </div>
           <div class="card card-body">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" href="{% url 'create_amc' %}">Create New AMC</a>
      <table class="table table-sm">
        <tr>
          <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Location</th>
          <th>AMC ID</th>
          <th>AMC Type</th>
            <th>AMC Status</th>
            <th>AMC Cost</th>
            <th>AMC Start</th>
            <th>AMC Expiry</th>

        </tr>
        {% for items in amc %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ items.customer }}</td>
            <td>{{ items.location }}</td>
          <td>{{ items.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ items.amc_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ items.amc_status }}</td>
            <td>{{ items.amc_cost }}</td>
            <td>{{ items.start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ items.end_date }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
<nav><div class="paginationDiv">
  <ul class="pagination" >
    {% if amc.has_previous %}
    <li>
      <a href="?page={{amc.previous_page_number}}" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true"><b>Prev</b></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if amc.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
    {% for p in amc.paginator.page_range %}
    &nbsp;<li class="{% if amc.number == p %}active{% endif %}"><a href="?page={{p}}"><b>{{p}}</b></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if amc.has_next %}
    <li>
      &nbsp;<a href="?page={{amc.next_page_number}}" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true"><b>Next</b></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

`

Now, Either I can make Paginator to use the object 'amc' in the context by passing it to 'page_obj' or changing to 'amc' will make Form filters to work, cant achieve both together. Please show me a work around for this?